# Spotify App Remote SDK: CouldNotFindSpotifyApp error on Google Pixel 3

Tags: android, spotify

**Device**
Google Pixel 3, Google Pixel 3 AVD (API 30)

**Operating System**
Android 10

I'm trying to build an app which integrates the Spotify App Remote SDK. However, when I try to connect to Spotify using the SDK, the CouldNotFindSpotifyApp error is thrown even though the Spotify app is installed on the device.

This is my first time posting on these forums, so if additional information is needed that I haven't provided, please bear with me.

Comment: Please include the code and the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to *allow Spotify to be searched* before trying to search for it! This may be common knowledge, but it wasn't to me.

Added this to the manifest file:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.spotify.music" />
</queries>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you have upgraded versions: Android 11 requires now you to do extra work when communicating with Spotify App
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility